# Running Javascript function from ng-change in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I haven't created a controller because I'm just using basic checkboxes with truth values.  However, on one I would like to call a Jquery function from ng-change.

This what I have:

```
Agree to terms:  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="terms"
ng-init="terms='Please Accept'" ng-change="termShow()"><br/>

##JQuery Function

function modShow()
{
    $('#smallModal').modal('show');
}
```

Is it possible for Angular to function this way?

Comment: Please paste all your code

Comment: @Sid the rest is irrelevant as far as the HTML.  The `function modShow()` is all I have for my Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

`ng-change="termShow()"`

AngularJS will try to call the function `termShow` in current scope context. If this function is not existing there Angular will go up to parent scopes, until rootScope, and looks in each scope for this function. So the easiest solution would be creating a small controller, which creates a new scope and contains this function.

Comment: I tried that, but when I created a controller all my expressions showed `{{exp}}`

Comment: What expressions? You don't show that in the code you used in your example.

Comment: Does the console in browser also shows an error? I bet it does. If you just see the expressions as you wrote them to html, it is a sign that a javascript error appears somewhere. Probably a simple syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Addition to `Armin`'s answer, you'll probably have to use the $modal service from angularui project (to make sure your expressions do compile and wont show up as `{{exp}}`). they did a great work implementing the service and it's easier to use their's than to write your own directive/service (believe me I've tried both :D)